# I would like to copy data into a new row on excel and create a new input row

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am new to VBA on excel and I am trying to automate a spreadsheet as much as possible.

I have attached an image of an example sheet. What I am trying to do is copy the data in cells K9/K10 into a new row on the table on the left. This table increases in number of rows every week and I want to be able to automate this process, so I can click a button and the data is inputted in the correct columns automatically and everything autofills with it.

[image]

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? We can't help if you don't show us the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: I only have experience with Recording macros, which does not help with this since it is not a repeatable process on the range of cells included. If this is too basic a question, perhaps I am in the wrong place as I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are calculating the value for Processed, but the code below will add a new row and populate every field apart from that one, simply put the code under the Sheet you are using.

This also assumes that your Percentage is calculated with a formula, which will get dropped into the new row without having to explicitly add it.

It will check for changes in cell K10 and if something has changed it will take them values and add a row to your table:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$K$10" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'get the last row with data on Column A
        ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(LastRow, 1) + 1 'add one to the Week Number
        ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(LastRow, 2) + 7 'add 7 to the Week Beginning Date
        ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = ws.Range("K9").Value + ws.Range("K10").Value 'get the Total
        ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = ws.Range("K9").Value 'copy the Passes
        ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = ws.Range("K10").Value 'copy the Fails
    End If
End Sub
```

All you need to do is, open your Workbook, press Alt+F11, then the VBA environment will open up, then double-click on the Sheet you are using and paste it there, like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I know enough to implement this solution. I need to do some more learning I think and it will make more sense. Thank you!

Comment: I've added a little more information as to where the code should go, please could you also mark my response as an answer if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks very much for your help!